# list(set) for nested lists?

Tags: python, math

I am currently working on a module that will compute the angle between a vector and the normal of a plane.

Anyhow to satisfy the conditions of computing the normal to the plane, I need 3 points in R3.

I have found a way to do this by converting the list elements to strings, however this complicates the code downstream. The following block of code aims to satisfy this condition. List t2 contains the strings and works well downstream, however I wish to work with a nested list (t1).

```
t1,t2=[],[] #B3
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    t1.append([s[i][0][0],s[i][2][4]])

    t2.append(s[i][0][0]+s[i][2][4])
u,j,k=list(set(t2)),[],[]
for item in u:
    j.append(t2.count(item))
if len(u) == len(j):
for i in range(0, len(u)):
    if j[i] >= 3:
        k.append([u[i]])

#For additional clarity:
List t1 looks as follows:
[['[7,', '158,'],
 ['[7,', '158,'],
 ['[51,', '158,'],
 ['[51,', '158,'],
 ['[51,', '158,'],
 ['[51,', '161,'],
 ['[51,', '161,'],
 ['[51,', '161,'],
 ['[298,', '114,'],
 ['[808,', '138,'],
 ['[808,', '138,']...
```

So within t1 if there exists 3 or more lists containing equivalent elements (such as ['[51,', '158,']) I wish to append these. The problem is that the set() does not work with nested lists.

Is there a way around this?
Cheers

Comment: Can you convert to a `set` of nested `tuple`?  `set(tuple(lst) for lst in l2)`

Comment: You want to use tuples rather than lists.  Tuples are essentially the same as lists, except they're immutable.  Because of this, they can be used as dict (and set) keys.  Just use parentheses in place of square brackets to create tuples.  To convert an existing list to a tuple, use `tuple(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you want to get all the lists with three or more instances and preserve the ordering you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) where keys are tuples and values are counts:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

t1 = [
    ['[7,', '158,'],
    ['[7,', '158,'],
    ['[51,', '158,'],
    ['[51,', '158,'],
    ['[51,', '158,'],
    ['[51,', '161,'],
    ['[51,', '161,'],
    ['[51,', '161,'],
    ['[298,', '114,'],
    ['[808,', '138,'],
    ['[808,', '138,']
]

d = OrderedDict()
for x in t1:
    t = tuple(x)
    d[t] = d.get(t, 0) + 1

[list(k) for k, v in d.items() if v >= 3] # [['[51,', '158,'], ['[51,', '161,']]
```

If ordering is not important you could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in t1)
[list(k) for k, v in takewhile(lambda x: x[1] >= 3, c.most_common())]
```

Comment: @ niemmi Ordering was actually rather useful for this particular purpose as there was lots of indexing necessary so the OrderedDict() module was very useful and works exactly as required. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Cast your mutable, non-hashable lists to immutable, hashable tuples which can be used as elements for a `set`:

```
new_t1 = list(set(map(tuple, t1)))
new_t1.sort(key=t1.index)  # preserves order of first occurrence in original list
new_t1 = [list(x) for x in new_t1]  # back to list of lists
```

Comment: Using `index` in the `sort` is pretty inefficient.